# Is it possible to use one tuple to index another?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, stdtuple

I have two tuples: one with the data I want, and another with a list of indeces for the first tuple. I want to use the second tuple to access items from the first tuple using `std::get`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    const auto tup     = std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6);
    const auto indeces = std::make_tuple(0, 1, 2);

    const int index = std::get<0>(indeces);
    const int value = std::get<index>(tup); // won't compile
    // value should equal 4
```

Of course it's obvious why this fails if you consider that `std::get` won't return `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int index = std::get<0>(indeces); // won't compile
```

Nevertheless, all the necessary information is provided at compile time, so I feel like there should be a way. Is there?

---

Note: My `indeces` tuple starts out its life as a parameter pack of ints. I made it into a tuple because I hoped that it would be easier to work with, but this may not be the case. If anyone can see a way of bypassing the `indeces` tuple and using the parameter pack ints directly to index the first tuple, that would a welcome answer too.

Comment: works in gcc 8: https://godbolt.org/z/VARw2q

Comment: `std::array<int, N>` seems more appropriate than `std::tuple<int, ..., int>`. Alternative with tuple is `std::tuple<std::integral_constant<int, I1>, ..., std::integral_constant<int, IN>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make them all `constexpr`

```
auto test()
{
    constexpr auto tup     = std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6);
    constexpr auto indeces = std::make_tuple(0, 1, 2);

    constexpr int index = std::get<0>(indeces);
    constexpr int value = std::get<index>(tup);
}
```

That being said, const integrals in C++ have special treatment and if they are initialized with a compile time constant they can be used in compile time contexts. So your code does work also.

Comment: @Evg ofc. Thank you